# VB 2012 - Attempting to get ElementID's Text from a Website

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to get text from a Element on a website

Websites Element Code:

```
<div class="info-box">
<span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow">
<i class="ion ion-ios-people-outline"></i>
</span>
<div class="info-box-content">
<span class="info-box-text">TOTAL MEMBERS</span>
<span class="info-box-number">34,396</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to get 34,396 from info-box-number.

There are 4 of these boxes that I need to get them from.
They are all the same except the Info-Box-Text and Info-Box-Number are different.

I attempted to use GetAttribute but, I kept getting a error.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim theElementCollection As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("info-text-box").GetAttribute("info-text-number").ToString()
End Sub
```

After I get the number I want it to go into a TextBox.